# how to show sqlsrv value in datetime picker in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, sql-server-2014-express

Hi i am currently developing a PHP websites where i want to show my date in to datetime picker.It is noted that i am using sql server 2014 express and datatype is Datetime.The following code from my project...

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var date_input=$('input[name="from_date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
  var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  date_input.datepicker({
   format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
   container: container,
   todayHighlight: true,
   autoclose: true,
  })
 
  
 })
</script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var date_input=$('input[name="to_date"]');
      //our date input has the name "date"
  var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  date_input.datepicker({
   format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
   container: container,
   todayHighlight: true,
   autoclose: true,
  })
 })
</script>
```

```html
 <tr><td class="col-sm-3"><span>From:</span></td><td> 

     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-left:-39px;">
       <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
         <i class="fa fa-calendar">
         </i>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" id="date1" name="from_date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text"  required/>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
 


</td></tr>

 <tr><td class="col-sm-3"><span>To:</span></td><td> 

     <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-left:-39px;">
       <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
         <i class="fa fa-calendar">
         </i>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" id="date2"  name="to_date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text" required/>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Here is the image of my project

[image]

I want to show my date from sql server 2014 express to datetimepicker in my PHP websites.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Man it worked for me.Here is the code

```html
  <input class="form-control" id="date1" name="from_date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text" value="<?php echo $row ['from_date']->format('m/d/Y');?>" required/>
```